# mysql query building output taking a long time

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a simple query that does

```
 select * 
   from t 
  limit 1;
```

on a remote mysql server.

I use squirrel(mysql client) to run it, it shows:

Query 1 of 1 elapsed time (seconds) - Total: 22.047, SQL query: 1.047, Building output: 21

why does building output take such a long time?  what does this process do?  when running from mysql command line, the whole process takes 0.3 secs (also remotely)

Comment: use another SQL-client ... does that change the execution time?

Comment: use another Mysql Client like sqlyog http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/

Comment: specify just the primary key column e.g. `select id from t limit 1;` does it make a substantial difference?